# Relational operators

Tags: c, relational-operators

I'm confused about the result of `test` function, which is `-1` in case below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int test(const void*, const void*);
int main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 5;
    int result = test(&a, &b);
    printf("Result: %d", result);
    return 0;
}

int test(const void* a, const void* b) {
    const double* da = (const double*)a;
    const double* db = (const double*)b;
    return (*da > * db) - (*da < *db);
}
```

`0x0135fb00` now is my value of da and address of a 
`0x0135faf4` now is my value of db and address of b

From what I know, relational operators return 1 if True, 0 if False, so in this case we should have:

`*da > *db --> 1` 
since value of `da` (address of a) is bigger than value of `db` (address of b).
`*da < *db --> 0` 
since value of `da` (address of a) is not smaller than value of `db` (address of b). 
So 1-0 is 1.

Just to specify, I've arrived at this conclusion by comparing value of da and value of db through debugger (I'm using Visual Studio with default C compiler). What am I missing?

PS: I've encountered this code on the official [GNU web site](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Comparison-Functions.html).

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(double)`?  I suspect you are not reading what you think you are reading...

Comment: Why did you decide to reinterpret pointers to `int` as pointers to `double`? that part is definitely not from the link in your question

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer to `int` as a pointer to `double`. Absolutely produces undefined behavior.

Comment: You're not comparing pointers, you're comparing what they point to, and through an incompatible pointer type at that.

Comment: Where do the other 32-bits for `double` come from? Get rid of `void` and use the proper type `int` (or `int *`) for all types. (unless you are working with the `qsort()` `compare()` prototype -- then get your casts right)

Comment: @Andrew correct me If I'm wrong, but in this case, since I'm casting an int (4 bytes) to a double (8 bytes), there is no loss of information. The unpredictable result now, could derived from BOM (endian type), so how 4 int bytes are translated to 8 double bytes.

Comment: @UnholySheep yes I missused the text on the link. "test" function should be related to double arguments, and not int as I did. Thank for pointed this out, but this doesn't solve my issue, since pointer casting is not illegal.

Comment: @Gene can you explain why? Comparing 2 derefenced double is not illegal. As I've explained in others comments, I'm casting pointers to the same types, and then dereferencing it. I'm not getting what it is wrong, thank you for your help.

Comment: @bersi Just because the code compiled doesn't mean it is correct. In your case you are casting pointers to an incompatible type (from `int*` to `double*`) thus invoking *undefined behavior*. In C it's always the programmers responsibility to ensure that the code does not violate such rules

Comment: Casting from `int` to `double` invokes an explicit conversion. Casting from `int*` to `double*` and dereferencing causes undefined behaviour. When you cast the address of an `int` to the address of a `double`, you are not changing the data at that address.

Comment: @DarkAtom thank you, I've got it. I'm still not getting what happens to other 4 bits of my number, since we are passing from 4 to 8 bits (garbage or 0, is BOM influencing the number). I will investigate on that.

Comment: @bersi Simple. Your `int` has 4 bytes (not bits). When you cast it to `double`, it takes 4 adjacent bytes in memory, which usually contain either garbage or some other variable (or, even a return address, so it is a security issue)

Comment: Bersi... your first conversion reads 32 bits - the values of `int a` and `int b` are concatenated.  The second conversion reads the next 32 bits - random stuff...

Comment: One other note is that on some (mostly old) architectures, doubles must be 8-byte aligned, and ints are 4 bytes, so this code could refuse to run entirely, e.g. with a "bus fault".

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you say:

> `*da > *db --> 1`

> since value of da (address of a) is bigger than value of db (address of b).

However, as you are dereferencing the pointers (using the `*` operator), the above statement instead tests whether whatever `da` *points to* is larger than whatever `db` *points to*.

If you actually want to compare the addresses, leave out the `*`, i.e. :

```
(da > db) - (da < db)
```

And if your end goal is to compare addresses, there's no need to cast the `void` pointers, so you can rewrite `test` as follows:

```
int test(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return (a > b) - (a < b);
}
```

Comment: Comparing pointers like that is only defined for pointers to objects of the same array. Which OP doesn't have, so those comparisons would also be *undefined behavior*

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong. I tried to change the types of `a` and `b`, from int to double, and then everything works. Appear that casting an int to double via pointers could lead to undefined value, since double is 4 bytes of garbage bigger than int. Is this correct?

Comment: The behavior of comparing pointers with `<` or `>` is not defined by the C standard for pointers that do not point to objects within the same aggregate (array, structure, et cetera).